# Change the size of a plot when plotting multiple plots in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to know if there is a way to define the size of a plot in R, when you are plotting different plots using the par(mfrow=c()) function.

As a simple example take this:

```
par(mfrow = c(3,1))
plot(1:2)
plot(1:2)
plot(1:2)
```

All plots will have the same size.

Is it possible, for instance, to make the size of the third plot different?
For example make it half the size of the other plots?

If I use this:

```
par(mfrow = c(3,1))
plot(1:2)
plot(1:2)
plot(1:2, ylim =c(0,1))
```

The ylim axis changes but no the size of the plot.

Thank you.

Comment: i use `layout` `layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3,4,4), nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))` give you 1 big+ 2 small+1 big graph

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will explore that function. Could you provide a simple example?

Comment: Try for example `layout(matrix(c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), 0, 3, 3, 0), nrow=3, byrow = T))` to have 2 "full" plots and one centralized smaller plot with half of the others' width.

Comment: also see the less used `?split.screen` which has a really nice example of how to use. also see sean anderson's paper [here, pdf](http://seananderson.ca/courses/11-multipanel/multipanel.pdf) and some [code here](https://github.com/seananderson/multipanel)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try `layout`
for example

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3,4,4), nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
plot(1,main=1)
plot(2,main=2)
plot(3,main=3)
plot(4,main=4)
```

[image]

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,1,1,2,3,4,4), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
plot(1,main=1)
plot(2,main=2)
plot(3,main=3)
plot(4,main=4)
```

give you 
[image]

Also you can use `par(fig= )`
for example

```
par(mar=c(2,2,2,1))
par(fig=c(0,7,6,10)/10)
plot(1,main=1)
par(fig=c(7,10,6,10)/10)
par(new=T)
plot(2,main=2)
par(fig=c(0,7,0,6)/10)
par(new=T)
plot(3,main=3)
par(fig=c(7,10,0,6)/10)
par(new=T)
plot(4,main=4)
```

Give you 
[image]

but i think layout better for use

Comment: But to answer my questions, is it possible to make, for example, plot number 4 half the height of plot number 1?

Comment: I think you should add an example using `0` to hold a space and give the result the OP wants.

Comment: Edit my answer for  "plot number 4 half the height of plot number 1"

Comment: What if I want to set titles to the plots? Since I am using `main` I cannot define a title now...

Answer (score 1):

another option would be to use ggarrange. the nice thing about it is that you can use ggarange not just on plots but also on "arranged" plots that you've created with ggarrange, which makes it easy to first arrange e.g. two smaller plots and then arrange them together with one bigger one.