# Specifying axes in base plot for multiple plots

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to make a plot with specific axes, while keeping the aspect ratio as 1.
the problem is there is parts of the plot that i don't need and want to remove. 
[image: Example of parts to remove]

I can manage it using margin:

```
## Creating Data 
x <- seq(1, 100, length.out = 100) 
y <- seq(1, 400, length.out = 100)
## Playing with margins 
par(fin = c(3.75, 5.3) , mar = c(2, 9, 1, 3) + 0.1 )
## Making 
plot(y ~ x ,asp = 1)
abline(v = -10)
abline(v = 120)
```

[image: Removed parts]

But if i want to plot multiple plots i dont know how to remove it

```
## Using mfrow 
par(mfrow = c(3,2))
for (i in 1:6) {
  plot(y ~ x ,asp = 1,xlim = c(0,100), ylim = c(0,400))
  abline(v = -10)
  abline(v = 120)
}
```

[image]

How can i do it for the multiple plots?

Comment: omit `asp=1` in the call.

Comment: But he wants that the view of the observations on the screen would reflect the aspect ratio of 1.

Comment: are you limited to base plot or can you use ggplot2?

Answer (score 0):

This might be closer, using the `layout` method (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319942/change-the-size-of-a-plot-when-plotting-multiple-plots-in-r) and [layout R documentation)](http://127.0.0.1:27083/library/graphics/html/layout.html):

```
x <- seq(1, 100, length.out = 100) 
y <- seq(1, 400, length.out = 100)

plot.new()
par(mai = c(0.6,0.5,0.3,0.3))
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
for (i in 1:6) {
  plot(y ~ x ,asp = 1, ylim = c(0,400))
  abline(v = -10)
  abline(v = 120)
}
```

The `par(mai=c(b,l,t,r))` option changes the size of the whitespace surrounding the subplots.

Comment: This is not really working, although better there are still the parts i wanted to remove.